# Angular4: data binding works only before initialization

Tags: angular, angular2-databinding

I have a simple component with a property `userFirstName`.

Now I just want to display this property. I have made a simple binding, and I initialize the `userFirstName` in the constructor but it works only when there it is the first command!

**So this works fine:** and it shows the "User Name" text.

```
this.userFirstName = "User Name";
this.loggedIn = localStorage.getItem("currentUser")!=null;
var currentUser = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
let user:User = JSON.parse(currentUser) ;
this.userFirstName = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
```

Now if I put `this.userFirstName = "User Name";` at the last, it doesn't work.

**So this doesn't work** and it shows empty string!

```
   this.loggedIn = localStorage.getItem("currentUser")!=null;
    var currentUser = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
    let user:User = JSON.parse(currentUser) ;
    this.userFirstName = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
    this.userFirstName = "User Name";
```

Here is the corresponding html:

```
<div>
     <a >Hello  {{userFirstName}} ! </a>
//some content
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since DOM is loaded faster, it will not wait for the response from the localStorage, so you will get that issue.

Fix :

**Method 1 :** Using `*ngIf`

```
<div *ngIf="userFirstName"> ... </div>
```

This will load the DOM only if there is a value in the userFirstName

**Method 2** : Making the service calls in the `constructor()`

```
constructor(){
    this.loggedIn = localStorage.getItem("currentUser")!=null;
    var currentUser = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
    let user:User = JSON.parse(currentUser) ;
    this.userFirstName = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
}
```

**Method 3** : Initializing the variable with a empty string during declaration itself.

```
userFirstName = "";
```